# how to style an <h:inputText> with CSS

Tags: jsf

so i'm trying to style my inputText but it doesn't work
here is my **XHTML** code

```
<h:form>
   <h:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="contactform">
       <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.formateur.nom}"  class="text-input" a:placeholder="Nom"  />
//rest of the form 
     <h:panelGrid>  
</h:form>
```

and my **CSS**

```
.contactform .text-input{
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.contactform .text-input:focus{
     border-color: #d9232d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class attribute in JSF components.

You should replace attribute "class" by "styleClass" in <h:inputText> tag